# Cocoapods: "ld: framework not found Realm for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, realm

I have been developing an application with cocoapods as dependency manager but i am not able to specify RealmSwift as *"private"* pod for one of my app's module/target (Cocoa Touch Framework).

With every try changing my podfile i am getting the following message from Xcode at build time:

> ld: framework not found Realm for architecture arm64 
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

By now, this is how my pod file looks like (right now my abstract_target is empty, but at the future will be filled with other pods):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

abstract_target 'pod-defaults' do

    target 'MyApp' do
        pod 'KeychainAccess', '~> 2.3'
    end

    target 'API' do
        pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
        pod 'TaskQueue', '~> 0.9'
    end

    target 'Data' do
        pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 1.0'
    end
end
```

When i am moving the RealmSwift pod to the root abstract_target I am not getting this error, but this is not my desired structure.

Someone can help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: When do you get this linker error? When building the app target? Then you're likely using Realm in there directly as well and you would need to make sure that you depend on it in your Podfile.